# Как правильно расставить дефисы и нужен ли дефис в словосочении?

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте, знатоки!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать правильно: модульно-(балльно-)-рейтинговая система (как нужно расставить дефисы?) и нужен ли дефис в словосочетании практико-ориентированный (или можно написать практико ориентированный?).
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что правило о слитном- дефисном написании прилагательных в современной практике далеко не всегда соблюдается, т.е. происходит постепенное изменение этого самого правила. Не могу точно сослаться на источник (статья лингвиста в одном из номеров "Русского языка"), но если первая часть слова заканчивается на -ико, то такие слова пишутся через дефис. Вообще, прилагательное может быть написано либо слитно, либо полуслитно (через дефис). Если раздельно, то это сочетание прилагательного с другим словом. И что это за форма  "практико"? (Т.е. все-таки "практико-ориентированный")

Comment: Вы знаете, это разумно. Формы на "-ико" действительно плохо смотрятся как графические слова, т.е. в окружении пробелов.  
А насчет несоблюдения правила... Оно действительно нуждается в корректировке. Но совет-то дать против существующего правила никак нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

~1. Нужно знать, что под этой самой бальной системой понимается. Если "сочетание модуля и рейтинга", то дефис нужен. Но в любом случае больше одного дефиса в одном слове использовать нельзя.
~2. Аналогично. Если это система, сочетающая ориентацию и практику, то необходим дефис.
Если же "ориентированная на практику", то логично без дефиса. Смущает, правда, необычность самого термина. Нельзя как-то по-другому назвать?

Хотя у Лопатина сам термин встречается и именно в дефисном написании: "практико-ориентированный". Так что логично исходить из этого.

Comment: Уважаемый behemothus! Не могли бы Вы, прежде чем отправить ответ, перечитывать его, у Вас часто бывают опечатки, затрудняющие понимание. Уверена, что Ваше написание слова "аналогично" - тоже опечатка. Спасибо за понимание.

Comment: Постараюсь :) Но проблема есть.
У меня интернет слабый (я в зоне неуверенного покрытия) и теряется связь вместе с полуготовым ответом. Поэтому правлю обычно уже после отправки.

Comment: Москва большая. ;)
Сейчас нам за флуд пропишут. ;)

Comment: Удаляем!!!